# Swift Memory Deinit During Reassignment

Tags: swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting, ciimage

Let's say I have a custom `CIImage` class.

```
import UIKit

class MyCIImage: CIImage {

    var VC:RealtimeDepthMaskViewController!

    deinit { print("Deinit") }

    override init(cvPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        super.init(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    }

    override init(cvPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, options: [CIImageOption : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: options)
    }

    convenience init(cvPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, VC:RealtimeDepthMaskViewController) {
        self.init(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        self.VC = VC
        print("Init")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Then we create and assign a variable.

```
let image:CIImage = MyCIImage(cvPixelBuffer: somePixelBuffer) //"Init"
```

Then, I want to reassign the variable

```
image = MyCIImage(cvPixelBuffer: someOtherPixelBuffer) //"Init" "Deinit"
```

The printout I would get from doing these 2 commands would be

```
"Init"
"Init"
"Deinit"
```

Why is the memory getting deinitialized at all and not just reassigned? Wouldn't the memory address stay the same and the item at which the memory address is just change? If not, is this a possible case? So that the memory @ address `image` is never nil, just constantly changing?

Comment: Every time a class is initialized, new memory is allocated. If you want to reuse an object with different data, you have to assign the image without a call to init(..)

Comment: Interesting. I shall play with that information. Thanks

Comment: First, I’m assuming it was `var image = ...`, not `let` (because you cannot replace a constant `let` reference). Second, assuming it was `var`, you’ve replaced the object referenced by `image` with a new instance and thereby discarding your reference to the prior instance (hence the `deinit` of the first instance).

Comment: Unrelated, but the image’s reference to `RealtimeDepthMaskViewController` is worrying. An image object has no business keeping references to view controllers. And if this is really a delegate pattern that you’re trying to implement, you’d generally use a protocol (to keep them loosely coupled) and make the reference weak (to avoid strong reference cycles).

Comment: Whoops - that was there for testing to play with retention cycles and try and determine why it was in memory if there was a strong reference to the VC. I understand that is bad pattern - more of a research thing. It is not there for actual purposes. It is a var, I did write the test on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do ...

```
var image: CIImage = MyCIImage(cvPixelBuffer: somePixelBuffer)
```

... that will result in your first “Init” logging statement.

When you then do ...

```
image = MyCIImage(cvPixelBuffer: someOtherPixelBuffer)
```

... that will do two things:

1. You are creating a new `MyCIImage` instance, that results in another “Init” logging message associated with this new instance.
2. But, because you’re replacing your strong reference, `image`, for the old `MyCIImage` with with a reference to the new one, you’re removing your strong reference to that first instance. And, because that first instance has no remaining strong references, it will be deallocated and you’ll see a “Deinit” logging message associated with it.

You asked:

> Why is the memory getting deinitialized at all and not just reassigned? Wouldn't the memory address stay the same and the item at which the memory address is just change?

Nope. When you create a new instance (with `MyCIImage(...)` syntax), it’s creating a new object with a new address. That’s just how objects and automatic reference counting works.

> If not, is this a possible case? So that the memory @ address image is never nil, just constantly changing?

The only way you can prevent it from getting a new address is if you refrain from creating a new instance of your type (i.e., if you only work with that original instance and avoid creating a new one).

But if it’s a new image, we just create a new instance for it and not worry about the fact that it’s a new object. Many of the properties (e.g. [`pixelBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1687604-pixelbuffer), [`cgImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1687603-cgimage), etc.) of your parent class, `CIImage` are read-only, and cannot be swapped out or changed behind the scenes. Your parent class, `CIImage`, really is intended for a single, unique image. As a general design principle, this is a very good thing, reducing many sorts of problems that can arise from unintended sharing. And in this case, it’s just how `CIImage` was designed to work.

Comment: I have come to that conclusion. Now the goal is how to appropriately go about my design pattern to obtain my goal. Thanks!